# Why is my interstitial ad not respecting policy?

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

I created an iOS app that simulates a shaver. 
The user turns on the shaver and it makes some noise, the user turns off the shaver and the noise stops and it shows an interstitial ad from AdMob.
So there's a button in the center of the screen to switch ON/OFF.
After three months of earnings I get this email from google saying that they **blocked the ads** for this reason:

> *LAYOUT ENCOURAGES ACCIDENTAL CLICKS - INTERSTITIAL ADS: Publishers are not permitted to encourage users to click AdMob interstitial ads
>   in any way.
>  This includes any implementation that may encourage
>   accidental clicks, such as placing an interstitial ad in a way that
>   prevents viewing the app’s core content or placing an interstitial ad
>   in a way that interferes with navigating or interacting with the app’s
>   core content and functionality.
>  Please review how you’ve
>   implemented interstitial ads and be mindful of the following common
>   examples of non-compliant implementations:
>
>  Interstitial ads
>   that appear before the app has opened or after the app has closed.
>   Interstitial ads that are triggered after a user closes another
>   interstitial ad.
>  Interstitial ads loading unexpectedly while a
>   user is viewing the app’s content.
>  Remember to only serve
>   interstitials between pages of content.
>  Interstitial ads that
>   trigger after every user click.
>  Interstitial ads that appear
>   during periods of game play or heavy user interaction.*

As I said before the ad shows up when the user pushes on the button to stop the sound. It's not suddenly popping up.
Can someone help me since I don't want my account to be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reasons that are stated in the email I would say that this is the case because either the ad is showing right after you clicked the button so the user might click on the ad when he/she is clicking once too many to stop the shaver (Which would be that it is loading while the user is viewing the app's content). Or it is because it is triggererd after every second user click (which is of course not after *every* click, but I think you might get the gist)

Of course it would be best if you could just contact Google to ask what seems to be the problem, but I do not think that will work. Another option would be to have a small part of the app itself show an ad instead of using an interstitial ad. But that is of course up to you to think of an alternative.

Comment: The ad shows when the user switches to OFF. I thought it was ok to show an ad after a click. I can't find a way to contact them. I need the interstitial on the app